# How to install the knitr-module in Lyx 2.0.3?

Tags: r, sweave, lyx, knitr

I just installed Lyx 2.0.3 on my iMac and MacBook Air. When trying to open a *.lyx document on the iMac I get the following error-message:

> "The module knitr has been requested by this document but has not been
>   found in the list of available modules. If you recently installed it,
>   you probably need to reconfigure LyX."

On the MacBook Air everything runs fine without any errors.

Any ideas how to install the knitr-module manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only requirement of the `knitr` module in LyX is R: you have to make sure the executable `Rscript` is in your PATH; you can test it by:

```
which Rscript
```

If you see the path to `Rscript`, you are ready to go (Tools-->Reconfigure); otherwise you have to tell LyX where is `Rscript` (add the path to `PATH prefix`):

[image: change path in lyx]

then reconfigure LyX.

You can get the path to `Rscript` by executing this in R:

```
R.home('bin')
```

Comment: shouldn't he also do `install.packages('knitr')` in `R` ?

Comment: oh yes, he should, and that is the next step; first he needs to make sure the `knitr` module is available, and that only requires R to be available

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Worked like a charme.

Comment: Where does one need to run `which Rscript` to test?  In the command window?  If so, do this assume a particular operating system?

Comment: Yes, in the command window (if on Windows, use `where` instead of `which`).