# Lyx cannot find knitr module

Tags: r, latex, knitr, lyx

I am migrating/branching from sweave to knitr and can run @yihui's [minimal example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw) in Rstudio but am having trouble making it run with Lyx (2.06). I get the message `The module knitr has been requested by this document but has not been found in the list of available modules.`

My PATH is `/usr/bin/Rscript` (per `which Rscript`, as per @yihui's suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645451/how-to-install-the-knitr-module-in-lyx-2-0-3)) so that appears visible, but lyx doesn't seem to see it.

I also did upgrade to R version 3.0.1 (Good Sport) today as a part of a larger system upgrade (Mint 13 to Mint 15), thus coinciding with when I started using Lyx so there may be other stuff going on at the same time. I do assume that R 2.15 and 3.0.1 have the same PATH (as noted, currently `/usr/bin/Rscript`) and that Rstudio and Lyx are not looking for different installations?

Comment: Did you try `Tools->Reconfigure`? Normally Linux users do not need to worry about `PATH` problems. Also check if `Rscript --version` works in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, @Yihui,I did try that. The Rscript version is `R scripting front-end version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)`. The 'rest' of the system sees `knitr`, seemingly fine.

Comment: Can you try removing your user-dir (back it up if there's something you want to keep)? Thus, exit LyX, remove ~/.lyx, start LyX. Also, how did you install 2.06? Did you use the [Ubuntu PPA](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3)? Did you compile from source? If you start a new document and go to Document > Settings > Modules, can you add knitr there?

Comment: @scottkosty I used the ubuntu PPA. I also followed your suggestion and removed `~./lyx` and lo and behold!!!! I can now see `RNW (knitr)`. I had an installation of Lyx pre-2.0.6 from a year ago or so, so something in the user dir may have compromised  the search path. Can't say what or why. You want to post as a response?

Comment: Yes, weird stuff can happen like that. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit LyX, remove (back-up if desired) `~/.lyx`, and start LyX.