# Knitr Lyx Problems

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, lyx

I'm working on getting `knitr` and LyX re-installed and working on my fresh OS setup. I had it working previously. I installed the latest version of R (3.0.1), Knitr is ver 1.3.3, LyX 2.0.6 including the MiKTex 2.9 distribution, and RStudio 0.97.551 on a Windows 7 Enterprise computer. I can get pdflatex output if I open up Lyx and simply view the tutorial, so the basic system is working.

I've tried running old LyX files I had with Knitr, but now they fail. Initially there appeared to be a path issue, as the `Rnw` file was never created. Now it fails on converting to `pdf` as in the errors below, having completed the creation of the `Rnw` file.

```
15:34:23.619: Previewing ...
15:34:23.639: (buffer-view: Ctrl+R)
15:34:23.786: Rscript --verbose --no-save --no-restore "C:/Program Files (x86)/LyX      2.0/Resources/scripts/lyxknitr.R" "C:/Users/tbrooks/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp6600/lyx_tmpbuf2/""knitr-minimal.Rnw" "C:/Users/tbrooks/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp6600/lyx_tmpbuf2/""knitr-minimal.tex" ISO-8859-15 "C:/Users/tbrooks/Desktop/"
15:34:23.813: The system cannot find the path specified.

Running: Rscript --verbose --no-save --no-restore "C:/Program Files (x86)/LyX   2.0/Resources/scripts/lyxknitr.R"     "C:/Users/tbrooks/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp6600/lyx_tmpbuf2/""knitr-minimal.Rnw"   "C:/Users/tbrooks/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp6600/lyx_tmpbuf2/""knitr-minimal.tex"   ISO-8859-15 "C:/Users/tbrooks/Desktop/"
..\..\..\src\support\Systemcall.cpp (273): Systemcall: 'Rscript --verbose --no-save --no-  restore "C:/Program Files (x86)/LyX 2.0/Resources/scripts/lyxknitr.R"   "C:/Users/tbrooks/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp6600/lyx_tmpbuf2/""knitr-minimal.Rnw"   "C:/Users/tbrooks/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp6600/lyx_tmpbuf2/""knitr-minimal.tex"   ISO-8859-15 "C:/Users/tbrooks/Desktop/"' finished with exit code 1
Error: Cannot convert file
----------------------------------------
An error occurred while running:
Rscript --verbose --no-save --no-restore "C:/Program Files (x86)/LyX
2.0/Resources/scripts/lyxknitr.R"
"C:/Users/tbrooks/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp6600/lyx_tmpbuf2/""knitr-m...
15:34:26.700: Error while previewing format: pdf2
```

If I use two examples linked below from Yihui Xie they both fail to compile to PDF in LyX. If I bring the `Rnw` file into R studio and try to compile it to pdf, it works for the `knitr-intro.Rnw` found here [(link)](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/tree/master/vignettes), but fails on the `opts_chunk` when I try `knitr-minimal.Rnw` created from the LyX file  [(here)](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/tree/master/inst/examples).

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated

UPDATE:
Yihui's answer below is partially helpful.

It solved the Rstudio issue, by changing to knitr.

It also partially solved the LyX issue. I did have a path to R in LyX, in fact I had this path: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin where there are R and Rscript executables, but given it is a 64 bit install i needed to go one further down to C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64.

I can now run R chunks, however I am still having trouble compiling some of the examples. I can compile `knitr-minimal.lyx`, but not `knitr-graphics.lyx`. I'm guessing this might have something to do with font or the tikzDevice. I will report back. Thanks

UPDATE2: In fact tikzDevice is not available for R 3.0.1, so that explains the failure of that demo. After adding the fonts in my file through `extrafonts` in R, I'm back in business. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the message log, I guess [R is not in your `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9645451/559676) ([also see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12451581/559676)).

For the problem with RStudio, I believe that is because you did not select `knitr` as your [weaving method](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/rstudio/) (by default it uses Sweave).

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue in one of the lyx files, other files were okay. Nothing I did seemed to work. Then I accidentally saved the lyx file I had issues with in a different directory, and surprisingly the problem was solved. I then realized that there was an "&" character in the folder name, which somehow prevented the execution of the r-codes!!