# knitr to pdflatex converter for lyx

Tags: r, latex, knitr, lyx

I am writing a book using LYX, have been using it for several years.  Some time ago, maybe close to a year, evidently after updating R, MikTeX, LYX, I started getting a dialog saying that my installation does not include a knitr to pdf converter, but I can use an external converter if I authorize it, which I do and things work.  But I have to do this every time I compile a new pdf file from LYX.  Does someone know why I am missing the converter, and how I can add it (have updated MikTeX many times, which doesn't do it)?

A secondary question:  It seems that the knitr to pdflatex converter controls the magnification of the pad file upon opening (over-riding Acrobat Pro DC 2017 magnification settings), and produces too small a magnification, that I have to increase every time I compile LYX to pdflatex.  Any suggestions on how to fix this very annoying problem.

Thanks a ton for any help anyone can provide.

Doug Martin

The dialog message I get upon trying to compile the LYX file to pdflatex:

```
\., LyX: An external converter requires your authorization 

The requested operation requires the use of a converter from
knitr to pdflatex: 

Rscript --verbose --no-save --no­restore $$s/scripts/lyxknitr.R $$p$$i $$p$$o $$e $$r

This external program can execute arbitrary commands on your system,
including dangerous ones, if instructed to do so by a maliciously
crafted LyX document
\ti/ould you like to run this converter? 
Only run if you trust the origin/sender of the LyX document!  

Do not run      Run     Always run for this document
```

Have searched Stack Exchange and other resources for an answer, but have not received one.  Doug

Comment: From the "R" perspective (not familiar with LyX), this sounds like an OS or LyX thing (at least that's consistent with how I envision things working). Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17734135/3358272) help at all? (ensuring "R" is in your `PATH`)

Answer (score 1):

According to this message:

https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg197583.html

the questions were added to protect against malicious code.  Another message later in that thread says one of the preference settings would let you disable the checks.